# An UI that slides through images

Tags: java, image, swing, mouseevent

I am trying to change what image is shown in the `JLabel`s of my User Interfaces.

The following class is a very simple test of the concept. The UI takes a folder full of images (the field `imageFolderPath`) and displays the first image, resized, in the only `JLabel`; clicking on the image prompts the UI to display the following image in the folder.

At least, it should. In reality, no image is shown. The fault is obviously of the method `reloadImage()`, either while rescaling the image or while repainting the `JLabel`, but I have not managed to find or correct the problem. Any idea?

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel boardImage;
    private ImageIcon icon;

    public String imageFolderPath = "C:\\modify\\it\\to\\suit\\your\\needs\\";
    public File[] files;
    public int indexImage = 0;

    public int imageResolution = 450;



    // =========================================================            
        // TODO | Constructors

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Test() {
        if( !new File(imageFolderPath).exists() )
            new File(imageFolderPath).mkdir();
        this.files = new File(imageFolderPath).listFiles();

        System.out.println("Can show:");
        for( File file : files )
            System.out.println("\t"+file.getName());


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, imageResolution, imageResolution);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // Every time the image is clicked, another one is shown
                indexImage++;
                reloadImage();
            }
        });
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        boardImage = new JLabel();
        boardImage.setBounds(0, 0, imageResolution, imageResolution);

        reloadImage();

        contentPane.add(boardImage);
    }

    // =========================================================            
        // TODO | Support methods

    /** Reloads the image of the {@link ChessBoard} at its current state.       */
    public void reloadImage() {
        if( files[indexImage % files.length].exists() )
            System.out.println("The file " + files[indexImage % files.length].getName() + " exists");
        else System.out.println("The file " + files[indexImage % files.length].getName() + " doesnt exists");

        // Reload the image - resized
        BufferedImage buffer = null;
        try {
            buffer = ImageIO.read( files[indexImage % files.length] );
            } catch (IOException e) {           e.printStackTrace();        }
        Image rescaledImage = buffer.getScaledInstance(imageResolution, imageResolution, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        icon = new ImageIcon(rescaledImage);

        boardImage = new JLabel(icon);
    //  boardImage.setText( files[indexImage % files.length].getName() );

        System.out.println("Is now showing " + files[indexImage % files.length].getName() );

        boardImage.repaint();
    }


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test frame = new Test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In reality, no image is shown.

```
boardImage = new JLabel(icon);
```

Don't create a new JLabel. The instance of that JLabel hasn't been added to the frame.

Instead just change the Icon of the existing JLabel:

```
//boardImage = new JLabel(icon);
boardImage.setIcon( icon );
```

The label will automatically repaint itself with the new Icon.